# How does ActiveSupport do month sums?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I was pleased and surprised to find that ActiveSupport does month sums in the way I wanted it to. Regardless of how many days are in the months in question, adding `1.month` to a particular `Time` will land you on the same day-of-the-month as the `Time`.

```
> Time.utc(2012,2,1)
=> Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 UTC 2012
> Time.utc(2012,2,1) + 1.month
=> Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 UTC 2012
```

the `months` method in `Fixnum` provided by activesupport does not give clues:

```
def months
  ActiveSupport::Duration.new(self * 30.days, [[:months, self]])
end
```

Following the `+` method in `Time`...

```
def plus_with_duration(other) #:nodoc:
  if ActiveSupport::Duration === other
    other.since(self)
  else
    plus_without_duration(other)
  end
end
```

...leads us to `since` in `Fixnum`...

```
def since(time = ::Time.current)
  time + self
end
```

...which leads us nowhere.

How/where is ActiveSupport (or something else) doing clever month math instead of just adding 30 days?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a really good question. The short answer is that `1.month` is an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object (as you already saw) and its identity is defined in two different ways:

- as `30.days` (in case you need/try to convert it to a number of seconds), *and*
- as 1 month (in case you try to add this duration to a date).

You can see that it still knows that it is equivalent to 1 month by inspecting its `parts` method:

```
main > 1.month.parts
=> [[:months, 1]]
```

Once you see proof that it still knows that it's exactly 1 month, it's less mysterious how calculations like `Time.utc(2012,2,1) + 1.month` can give the correct result even for months that don't have exactly 29 days, and why it gives a different result than `Time.utc(2012,2,1) + 30.days` gives.

**How do `ActiveSupport::Duration` conceal their true identity?**

The real mystery for me was how it hides its real identity so well. We *know* that it is a `ActiveSupport::Duration` object, yet it's very difficult to get it to *admit* that it is!

When you inspect it in a console (I'm using Pry), it looks exactly like (and claims to *be*) a normal Fixnum object:

```
main > one_month = 1.month
=> 2592000

main > one_month.class
=> Fixnum
```

It even claims to be equivalent to `30.days` (or `2592000.seconds`), which we've shown to be not true (at least not in all cases):

```
main > one_month = 1.month
=> 2592000

main > thirty_days = 30.days
=> 2592000

main > one_month == thirty_days
=> true

main > one_month == 2592000
=> true
```

So to find out whether an object is a `ActiveSupport::Duration` or not, you can't rely on the `class` method. Instead, you' have to ask it point-blank: "Are you or are you not an instance of ActiveSupport::Duration?" Confronted with such a direct question, the object in question will have no choice but to confess the truth:

```
main > one_month.is_a? ActiveSupport::Duration
=> true
```

Mere Fixnum objects, on the other hand, must hang their heads and admit that they are not:

```
main > 2592000.is_a? ActiveSupport::Duration
=> false
```

You can also tell it apart from regular Fixnums by checking if it responds to `:parts`:

```
main > one_month.parts
=> [[:months, 1]]

main > 2592000.parts
NoMethodError: undefined method `parts' for 2592000:Fixnum
from (pry):60:in `__pry__'
```

**Having an array of parts is great**

The cool thing about having an array of parts is that it allows you to have duration defined as a mix of units, like this:

```
main > (one_month + 5.days).parts
=> [[:months, 1], [:days, 5]]
```

This allows it to accurate calculate such things as:

```
main > Time.utc(2012,2,1) + (one_month + 5.days)
=> 2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC
```

... which it would *not* be able to calculate correctly if it simply stored *only* a number of *days* or *seconds* as its value. You can see this for yourself if we first convert `1.month` to its "equivalent" number of seconds or days:

```
main > Time.utc(2012,2,1) + (one_month + 5.days).to_i
=> 2012-03-07 00:00:00 UTC

main > Time.utc(2012,2,1) + (30.days + 5.days)
=> 2012-03-07 00:00:00 UTC
```

**How does `ActiveSupport::Duration` work? (Gory implementation details)**

`ActiveSupport::Duration` is actually defined (in `gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/duration.rb`) as a subclass of `BasicObject`, which according to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html), "can be used for creating object hierarchies independent of Ruby's object hierarchy, proxy objects like the Delegator class, or other uses where namespace pollution from Ruby's methods and classes must be avoided."

`ActiveSupport::Duration` uses `method_missing` to delegate methods to its `@value` variable.

**Bonus question**: Does anyone know why an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object *claims* to not respond to `:parts` even though it actually *does*, and why the parts method isn't listed in the methods list?

```
main > 1.month.respond_to? :parts
=> false

main > 1.month.methods.include? :parts
=> false

main > 1.month.methods.include? :since
=> true
```

**Answer**: Because `BasicObject` does not define a `respond_to?` method, sending `respond_to?` to an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object will end up calling its `method_missing` method, which looks like this:

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block) #:nodoc:
  value.send(method, *args, &block)
end
```

`1.month.value` is simply the Fixnum `2592000`, so it effectively ends up calling `2592000.respond_to? :parts`, which of course is `false`.

This would be easy to solve, though, by simply adding a `respond_to?` method to the `ActiveSupport::Duration` class:

```
main > ActiveSupport::Duration.class_eval do
           def respond_to?(name, include_private = false)
               [:value, :parts].include?(name) or
               value.respond_to?(name, include_private) or
               super
             end
         end
=> nil

main > 1.month.respond_to? :parts
=> true
```

The explanation for why `methods` incorrectly omits the `:parts` method is the same: because the `methods` message simply gets delegated to value, which of course does *not* have a `parts` method. We could fix this bug as easily as adding our own `methods` method:

```
main > ActiveSupport::Duration.class_eval do
         def methods(*args)
           [:value, :parts] | super
         end
       end
=> nil

main >  1.month.methods.include? :parts
=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the magic happens in ActiveSupport's [core_ext/date/calculations.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a8f2860d0e7db86c61bb70935006100b04667ab1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L108):

```
def advance(options)
  options = options.dup
  d = self
  d = d >> options.delete(:years) * 12 if options[:years]
  d = d >> options.delete(:months)     if options[:months]
  d = d +  options.delete(:weeks) * 7  if options[:weeks]
  d = d +  options.delete(:days)       if options[:days]
  d
end

def >>(n)
  y, m = (year * 12 + (mon - 1) + n).divmod(12)
  m,   = (m + 1)                    .divmod(1)
  d = mday
  until jd2 = self.class.valid_civil?(y, m, d, start)
    d -= 1
    raise ArgumentError, 'invalid date' unless d > 0
  end
  self + (jd2 - jd)
end
```

Looks like Ruby 1.9+ handles this, so this code is only used when Rails is used with older Ruby versions.

Comment: nice! do you know where/when `advance` is invoked? if you could explain why I didin't find this while following the code in my question that would be helpful.

Comment: also, where do you see the code being selectively used based on ruby version?

Comment: Check out the top of the linked file (line 10) for the Ruby version code.

Comment: good stuff-- i still don't see where advance is used for sums, i only seeing it used in `months_ago`, `weeks_ago`, etc.