# Ruby convert decimal duration (day|week|month|year) to end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `start_at`, a decimal `quantity` and an `interval` which is one of `day | week | month | year`.

```
start_at = Time.parse('2016-01-01 00:00:00 UTC') # leap year
quantity = BigDecimal.new('1.998') # changed from 2.998, should end on 2/29/16 sometime
interval = 'month' # could be any of day|week|month|year
```

With whole numbers, I've used duration i.e. `1.month`, and I looked at `Date#advance`, though it only recognizes integer values.

It would seem simple but I cannot find anything in the standard libraries or in ActiveSupport.

References:

- [SO answer potentially used for input to `Date#advance`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24872496/2363935)
- [SO explanation of duration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024762/2363935)

**Question**

How can I establish the `end_at` date from a decimal?

**Why? What purpose?**

Proration to the second for a given amount *and* given interval.

**Expectations**

I'm looking for an `end_at` to the second as accurate as possible with respect to *advancing* the next `interval`(s) by the decimal `quantity`.  Given `interval = 'month'`, for the fractional part, when you pass the start of the month, means you are `in` that month and using it's duration.  For example, January 2016 is 31 days, while February (leap) is 29 days (only in the leap year).

Comment: Are you trying to advance a datetime by 2.998 months?

Comment: that does not even make sense. the length of a month differs depending on the month at hand. so if you take month as a fixed 30 day interval, just calculate everything based on that assumption using the seconds 30 days have.

Comment: @phoet - that is exactly why this is not straight-forward, otherwise you would do something like `30.days.to_i * quantity`.

Comment: @WesFoster yes, I've updated the question.  But keep in mind it could be 2.998 years or days or weeks.  This is for prorated recurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your best option is to use Ruby's date methods to advance time based on the whole number of the decimal, then calculate how many seconds your fraction is of your current interval.

So for 1.998 months, advance time 1 month. Find the current month you are in and get the .998 of the seconds in that month (i.e. for July, 31x24x60x60x.998) and then advance time that many seconds.

Answer (score 1):

What does advancing time a fractional month mean?

Lets say we have the following date `2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. It is easy to advance exactly 1 whole month, we simply increment the number that represents months: `2015-02-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Alternatively, we could view this as adding 31 days, which we know is the number of days in January.

But what if we want to advance 0.5 months from `2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`?

We can't just increment like we did when advancing a whole month. Since we know January has 31 days, perhaps we could just advance 15.5 days: `2015-01-16 12:00:00 UTC`. That sort of works.

How about 1.5 months from `2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`? If we combine our previous approaches, we'd first increment, getting us to 0.5 left to advance and `2015-02-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Then we'd take half of 28 and get to `2015-02-15 00:00:00 UTC`.

But wait, what if instead we took the total number of days between the two months and then took 3/4 of that? Like 2(month) * (3/4), which would simplify to (3(month)) / 2, or 1.5(month). Lets try it.

```
(28 days + 31 days) * 0.75 = 44.25 days
```

Now adding that to `2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` we get `2015-02-14 06:00:00 UTC`. That's three-quarters of a day off from our other answer.

The problem here is that the length of a month varies. So fractional months are not consistently definable.

Imagine you have two oranges. One contains a little bit more juice than the other (perhaps 31ml and 29ml of juice). Your recipe calls for the juice of 1.5 oranges. Depending on which one you decide to cut in half, you could have either 44.5 ml or 45.5 ml. But if your recipe calls for 40 ml of orange juice, you can pretty consistently measure that. Much like you can consistently (kind of) increment a date by 40 days.

Time is really tricky. We have leap seconds, leap years, inconsistent units (months), timezones, daylight saving time, etc... to take into account. Depending on your use case, you could attempt to approximate fractional months, but I'd highly recommend trying to avoid the need for dealing with fractional months.

Comment: I appreciate you describing the details of the problem, it is the reason I'm asking the question.  This is not quite true though: `The problem here is that the length of a month varies. So fractional months are not consistently definable.` They are definable (other than earth rotation time adjustments) otherwise we wouldn't have a future calendar.  I've updated the question with expectations, and it is not something that is avoidable when determining an `end_at` for a prorated amount.

Comment: Any given month, e.g. `January 2015` is consistently definable. My entire point is that `0.23 months` depends on which month you are dealing with, which means that on its own, `0.23 months` is not consistently definable. `0.23 of February 2015` is however. Now that I know what your particular use case is, I think this bit of my original answer applies: `Depending on your use case, you could attempt to approximate fractional months, but I'd highly recommend trying to avoid the need for dealing with fractional months.` This is a case where it is reasonable to deal with fractional months.

Comment: `start_at` was always defined (and did not change), so the future is/was defined.  Suggesting avoidance of the problem is perhaps not the best way to answer a SO question.